# Sklearn predict using a subset of my data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Is there a way to use predict on a selection of rows from a pandas dataset? As an example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)

selection = [True, True, False, False, True, False]
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "A": [1, 5, 3, 6, 5, 7],
        "B": ["a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"],
        "c": [5, 7, 4, 6, 5, 2],
    }
)

clf.predict(data[selection])
```

The idea is to use the predict method of the classifier **only** on the rows where `selection` is `True` while retaining the rows where `selection` is `False` as `NaN`. In this case the output should be something like:

```
[1, 0, NaN, NaN, 1, NaN]
```

Using `clf.predict(data[selection])` I obviously get the results of the classifier but I lose the order of the original dataframe.

Comment: what do you mean by order that is lost?

Comment: In this case, using `clf.predict(data[selection])` I'd get `[1,0,1]` as output while I would like to retain the columns where selection is False as `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
data["selection"] = selection

selected_cols = data.columns[:-1]
def predict(x):
    if x.selection:
        return ("model.predict(x[selected_cols])") # call your model here 
    else:
        return np.NAN

data.apply(predict, axis=1)

0    model.predict()
1    model.predict()
2                NaN
3                NaN
4    model.predict()
5                NaN
dtype: object
```